# React router not working when navigating using url

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am getting an error Cannot GET /'page' when trying to navigate using url to a path in React Router. Navigating from application works perfectly fine. Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const path = require('path');



app.use(express.static('build'));
app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('Server is up on port: '  + port);
})
```

I've tried adding this code snippet to my server but it didn't work:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './public/index.html'), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(500).send(err)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: what is the error that you receive? maybe update the question to show it

Comment: done, sorry for that